# Match URL and it's sub directories

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I write a regex to match `/path/subpath` and all `/path/subpath/*`, but not `/path/subpathrandomcharacters`

I am currently trying this `\/path\/subpath.*`

But this is also matching `/path/subpathrandomcharacters`

Comment: how can we distinguish `/*`and `randomcharacters`

Comment: @xianshenglu `subpath` is a string, example `articles` and with `randomcharacters` it would be something like `articlesawiojd` or `articlesanyrandomchar` and `/*` would be `/articles/edit` or `/articles/delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you check the value of the path/subparth, then it can either have a slash then anything or nothing.

```
\/path\/subpath(\/.*)*
```

https://www.regextester.com/?fam=103013

Comment: This is still matching /path/subpathrandomcharacters but only a part of it

Comment: @LanceToth that is just the regex utility showing that it exists as a substring, but a regex compare would fail on a whole string. So it wouldn't be an issue.